# Can someone explain me how YOLO draws bounding boxes around the objects?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

In the paper, You Only Look Once:Unified, Real-Time Object detection by Joseph Redmon, it is said that using YOLO we can detect the object along with it's class probability. Can someone explain me how YOLO draws bounding boxes around the objects for object detection with the help of the following code?

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
mask_shape = tf.shape(y_true)[:4]

cell_x = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(GRID_W), [GRID_H]), (1, GRID_H, GRID_W, 1, 1)))
cell_y = tf.transpose(cell_x, (0,2,1,3,4))

cell_grid = tf.tile(tf.concat([cell_x,cell_y], -1), [BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 5, 1])

coord_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)
conf_mask  = tf.zeros(mask_shape)
class_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)

seen = tf.Variable(0.)

total_AP = tf.Variable(0.)

"""
Adjust prediction
"""
### adjust x and y      
pred_box_xy = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., :2]) + cell_grid

### adjust w and h
pred_box_wh = tf.exp(y_pred[..., 2:4]) * np.reshape(ANCHORS, [1,1,1,BOX,2])

### adjust confidence
pred_box_conf = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., 4])

### adjust class probabilities
pred_box_class = y_pred[..., 5:]

"""
Adjust ground truth
"""
### adjust x and y
true_box_xy = y_true[..., 0:2] # relative position to the containing cell

### adjust w and h
true_box_wh = y_true[..., 2:4] # number of cells across, horizontally and vertically

### adjust confidence
true_wh_half = true_box_wh / 2.
true_mins    = true_box_xy - true_wh_half
true_maxes   = true_box_xy + true_wh_half

pred_wh_half = pred_box_wh / 2.
pred_mins    = pred_box_xy - pred_wh_half
pred_maxes   = pred_box_xy + pred_wh_half       

intersect_mins  = tf.maximum(pred_mins,  true_mins)
intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)
intersect_wh    = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]

true_areas = true_box_wh[..., 0] * true_box_wh[..., 1]
pred_areas = pred_box_wh[..., 0] * pred_box_wh[..., 1]

union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas
iou_scores  = tf.truediv(intersect_areas, union_areas)

true_box_conf = iou_scores * y_true[..., 4]

### adjust class probabilities
true_box_class = tf.to_int32(y_true[..., 5])

"""
Determine the masks
"""
### coordinate mask: simply the position of the ground truth boxes (the predictors)
coord_mask = tf.expand_dims(y_true[..., 4], axis=-1) * COORD_SCALE

### confidence mask: penalize predictors + penalize boxes with low IOU
# penalize the confidence of the boxes, which have IOU with some ground truth box < 0.6
true_xy = true_boxes[..., 0:2]
true_wh = true_boxes[..., 2:4]

true_wh_half = true_wh / 2.
true_mins    = true_xy - true_wh_half
true_maxes   = true_xy + true_wh_half

pred_xy = tf.expand_dims(pred_box_xy, 4)
pred_wh = tf.expand_dims(pred_box_wh, 4)

pred_wh_half = pred_wh / 2.
pred_mins    = pred_xy - pred_wh_half
pred_maxes   = pred_xy + pred_wh_half    

intersect_mins  = tf.maximum(pred_mins,  true_mins)
intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)
intersect_wh    = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]

true_areas = true_wh[..., 0] * true_wh[..., 1]
pred_areas = pred_wh[..., 0] * pred_wh[..., 1]

union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas
iou_scores  = tf.truediv(intersect_areas, union_areas)

best_ious = tf.reduce_max(iou_scores, axis=4)
conf_mask = conf_mask + tf.to_float(best_ious < 0.6) * (1 - y_true[..., 4]) * NO_OBJECT_SCALE

# penalize the confidence of the boxes, which are responsible for corresponding ground truth box
conf_mask = conf_mask + y_true[..., 4] * OBJECT_SCALE

### class mask: simply the position of the ground truth boxes (the predictors)
class_mask = y_true[..., 4] * tf.gather(CLASS_WEIGHTS, true_box_class) * CLASS_SCALE       

"""
Warm-up training
"""
no_boxes_mask = tf.to_float(coord_mask < COORD_SCALE/2.)
seen = tf.assign_add(seen, 1.)

true_box_xy, true_box_wh, coord_mask = tf.cond(tf.less(seen, WARM_UP_BATCHES), 
                      lambda: [true_box_xy + (0.5 + cell_grid) * no_boxes_mask, 
                               true_box_wh + tf.ones_like(true_box_wh) * np.reshape(ANCHORS, [1,1,1,BOX,2]) * no_boxes_mask, 
                               tf.ones_like(coord_mask)],
                      lambda: [true_box_xy, 
                               true_box_wh,
                               coord_mask])

"""
Finalize the loss
"""
nb_coord_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(coord_mask > 0.0))
nb_conf_box  = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(conf_mask  > 0.0))
nb_class_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(class_mask > 0.0))

loss_xy    = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_box_xy-pred_box_xy)     * coord_mask) / (nb_coord_box + 1e-6) / 2.
loss_wh    = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_box_wh-pred_box_wh)     * coord_mask) / (nb_coord_box + 1e-6) / 2.
loss_conf  = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_box_conf-pred_box_conf) * conf_mask)  / (nb_conf_box  + 1e-6) / 2.
loss_class = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=true_box_class, logits=pred_box_class)
loss_class = tf.reduce_sum(loss_class * class_mask) / (nb_class_box + 1e-6)

loss = loss_xy + loss_wh + loss_conf + loss_class

nb_true_box = tf.reduce_sum(y_true[..., 4])
nb_pred_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(true_box_conf > 0.5) * tf.to_float(pred_box_conf > OBJ_THRESHOLD))

total_AP = tf.assign_add(total_AP, nb_pred_box/nb_true_box) 

loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss_xy, loss_wh, loss_conf, loss_class, loss, total_AP/seen], message='DEBUG', summarize=1000)

return loss
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://hackernoon.com/efficient-implementation-of-mobilenet-and-yolo-object-detection-algorithms-for-image-annotation-717e867fa27d) is a good explanation:

> YOLO divides each image into a grid of S x S and each grid predicts N bounding boxes and confidence. The confidence reflects the accuracy of the bounding box and whether the bounding box actually contains an object(regardless of class). YOLO also predicts the classification score for each box for every class in training. You can combine both the classes to calculate the probability of each class being present in a predicted box.

Look at the code:

```
### adjust x and y      
pred_box_xy = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., :2]) + cell_grid

### adjust w and h
pred_box_wh = tf.exp(y_pred[..., 2:4]) * np.reshape(ANCHORS, [1,1,1,BOX,2])
```

Here, `cell_grid` is an evenly-spaced matrix of coordinates of default bounding boxes (anchors). `y_pred[..., :2]` contains predictions of offsets for `x` and `y` coordinates for the anchors. `y_pred[..., 2:4]` has predictions for width and height resize for each anchor. Having chosen anchors with a high confidence predicted, YOLO combines default locations of the anchors with the offsets predicted for them - and here you got your bounding box coordinates.

Pay attention, that anchors are relatively small (grid cells on the left image), so to detect a large object, YOLO predicts fairly large offsets for an anchor located somewhere close to the center of the object.

[image]